# PostgreSQL – waiting for checkpoint to complete

Tags: postgresql

When trying to perform `pg_basebackup` on a replica, I always get the following message:

```
postgres@db1:~/10$ pg_basebackup -h foo.bar.com -U repluser -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -v -P 
pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
```

I've tried waiting, but nothing happens. Is it possible to speed up the process?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Call `pg_basebackup` with the option `--checkpoint=fast` to force a fast checkpoint rather than waiting for a spread one to complete.

Comment: Read D. Langhorn's answer below regarding the impact of using this option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65793988/1205339

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to force a checkpoint to complete. To do so, run `CHECKPOINT;` on the master server:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
postgres=# CHECKPOINT;
```

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to point out that while the accepted answer of running 'CHECKPOINT' command on the primary server is correct, it is not meant to be run during normal operation, this is according to postgres documentation which you can see here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-checkpoint.html

So be sure and not do this while the server is processing normal operations from your apps etc.